# How to download javadocs for mvn dependencies through mvn command line?

Tags: maven

I need to download javadocs for a Maven artifact through command line.

I have tried these two versions, both have failed as follows.  What is the fix?

```
mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=http://maven-repository.com/ -Dartifact=com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1 -Ddest=C:\JarFilesDownload\jackson-databind.jar -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true
```

This one downloaded the dependency but did not download the javadocs.

```
mvn dependency:sources -Dclassifier=javadoc -Dartifact=com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1 -Ddest=C:\JarFilesDownload\jackson-databind.jar
```

This one is giving this error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:sources (default-cli): Goal requires
>        a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\jaligama). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`$ mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=com.fasterxml.jackson.core -DartifactId=jackson-
databind -Dversion=2.6.1 -Dclassifier=javadoc`

Refer to [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html#classifier), if you use `artifact` then `classifier` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Add this into `settings.xml` in `.m2` folder.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>downloadSources</id>
        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: Initially, there was no settings.xml in .m2.  The .m2 folder on windows is in my userprofile folder.

Comment: I have added the settings.xml to .m2 folder earlier.  I did same it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the Javadoc JAR, you don't even need to use Maven:

```
curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.1/jackson-databind-2.6.1-javadoc.jar
```

Comment: And how did you find out the URL?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I probably grabbed it from Central: Go to https://search.maven.org/, search for "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1", click the "Download" button and choose "javadoc.jar".

Comment: You may want to add these instructions to your answer - it makes it much more useful to future readers who might need this for a different artifact.  Note, however, that it doesn't install the jar file in the local maven repository making it less useful to IDE's.